# How to check if a template type parameter is a typelist?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I plan to use either boost::mp11 or brigand for my TMP. Here I use some pseudo code to illustrate what I want to do:

```cpp
template< typename... Types >
class factory
{
  // if the passing type is a typelist, 
  //   then use for_each() to get types out of it one by one.
  // else 
  //   do something.
}
```

So the user of `class factory` may pass in regular types (int, bool, etc.) or a typelist (either brigand or mp11 typelist). I want my code inside the `class factory` can pick types from the variadic template pack and do different processing according to whether it's a typelist or not? For example:

```cpp
factory<int, bool, typelist>       f1;
factory<typelist1, int, typelist2> f2
factory<typelist>                  f3
```

I did not find the two libraries (mp11, brigand) provide any facility function to check whether a type is a typelist. Anyone can share some thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

oh, just now, I found this `mp_is_list<L>` from MP11 document. I guess I can make use of that.